# Making a PNG to PDF with very high quality

Tags: fonts, vector, inkscape, logo, pdf

I have seen that several authors of scientific papers include in their work, black and white graphics (university logos mainly) that appear to have an incredibly high resolution. I have found the Universidad Nacional Autónoma de México and my university logo with that quality, but recently my university logo has experienced some changes so the one I have no longer works.

I was able to remove the colors of my university logo with a software called Pinta, but the output wasn´t perfect (I got very thin lines) and not a very good quality.

I include de logos I am talking about 
[image: UNAM LOGO]

That file is in PDF.

I have read that a way to acomplish this is to create a "font" with just a ligature of the logo, or convert a PNG file to a Vector and save it as PDF. I tried this last option with inkscape, but it looks blurry due to some gray lines produced when I trace my image.

So my question is, How can I acomplish to get a PDF file with the logo of my college in high quality? (I don't know much about graphic design software or theory)

This is my college Logo.

[image: ITC LOGO]

Comment: I agree that you are coming to this from the wrong direction. PNG is a screen format generally deployed at 72 dpi and RGB (colour). Assuming you want the higher resolution for printing (?) you would require 240 dpi and CMYK. In this case my approach would be to trace / re-draw the logo with Illustrator as a vector, saved out as an EPS. If this is a one - off need and time is short, the down and dirty method would be to convert the RGB / PNG to a CMYK / TIF in Photoshop (maintaining a transparent backdrop) It depends on the final size you require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your images are printable without fixing if you do not need them higher than 5 cm. If you need them as 20 cm high, they can be enlargened wthout losing the sharpness by OnOne Perfect Resize. That will unfortunately reveal some bad edges, but they were easy to fix.

This space only allows me to show a couple of snippets as screenshots about the enlargening results:

[image]

[image]

Vectorizig is not a must. It's another quessing process that easily give unwanted results.

The grey edges that you mentioned are a part of the ITCelaya logo. Unfortunately they are so thin that your tracing software struggles. Adobe Illustrator is not more clever. A proper CAD drawing vectorizer is surely better because it assumes all lines and curves to be done with drawing tools that produce solid edges without sharp spikes in or out. Oly corners are assumed to be sharp.

ADDENDUM: If you have a right to use these logos and their owners even keep it preferable, they surely send high resolution versions to you.

Answer (score 1):

See whether you can get a vector version of the logo. From the way it looks, it has been created with a vector based software (most likely Adobe Illustrator).

If that is not possible, vectorize it yourself, in Illustrator, or with another suitable tool.

Answer (score 0):

There are several websites such as png2pdf.com that offer to convert between images, pdfs, and many other file formats.

Answer (score 0):

PDF files are able to store vector drawings as original vectors. If you have a pdf like a flyer where that logo is used you can try opening it in inkscape to see if you can use the logo and delete the other stuff.